# Index indefinida quando desloga

Tags: php

Fiz um teste e coloquei uma forma de identificar quando o usuário está logado no site, e esse está funcionando numa boa. Mas quando eu me deslogo e vou na index, que é a página que pus o código, aparece o erro

> Notice: Undefined index: nivel in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\site tcc\index.php on line 5

Queria saber um modo de tirar isso quando estiver deslogado, e só aparecer a mensagem que eu coloquei para os usuários que fizeram o login. Código que eu usei

```
<?php
session_start();
include "php/conexao.php";

if($_SESSION['nivel'] == "admin" ||  $_SESSION['nivel']== "usuario"){ 
echo "oi logado";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o isset() para verificar se existe o index 'nivel' na sessão. Dessa forma ele não vai gerar um erro caso não exista.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['nivel'])){ 
  echo "oi logado";
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigada, era isso mesmo!!

Comment: Que bom!! De nada!